# bitbake BBPATH confusion

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In the bitbake manual (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) it says:

> 3.3.1. Locating Include and Class Files
>
> BitBake uses the BBPATH variable to locate needed include and class files. The BBPATH variable is analogous to the environment variable PATH.
>
> 3.3.3. include Directive
>
> BitBake understands the include directive. This directive causes BitBake to parse whatever file you specify, and to insert that file at that location. The directive is much like its equivalent in Make except that if the path specified on the include line is a relative path, BitBake locates the first file it can find within BBPATH.
>
> As an example, suppose you needed a recipe to include some self-test definitions:
>
> include test_defs.inc

However, I see many openembedded-core recipes that include files that seem to be relative to the file they are being included from rather than being in a directory in `BBPATH`, i.e.

Assume we have this directory structure:

```
mything.bb
mything.inc
include/mything.inc
```

And mything.bb contains:

```
require mything.inc
require include/mything2.inc
```

However, these files are not in the BBPATH.  I run bitbake -e mything.bb and BBPATH clearly does not contain the directory containing `mything.inc` or `include/mything2.inc`.

So the question is, is it true that include/require directives first search for the file relative to the file the directive appears in? Then and the falls back to searching for it in the BBPATH? If so, is this feature just missing from the bitbake user manual documentation?

Comment: Yes, it looks that it's still not clear in manual, here it was discussed http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2016-March/118879.html

Comment: Surprising that such a fundamental aspect of bitbake is documented so incorrectly. Looks like I'll be digging into the code to find out what it's really doing. And the worst part is that since it isn't documented, the behavior could change at any point. They could change which paths get checked first or remove the ability to include based on the includer's path. Bleh, this just leaves a bad taste in my mouth about bitbake.

Comment: 1.6 is a pretty old version. This has changed in the latest version of the docs: 

3.4.1. Locating Include and Class Files

BitBake uses the BBPATH variable to locate needed include and class files. Additionally, BitBake searches the current directory for include and require directives.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#sharing-functionality

Comment: @AlexanderKanavin yes, I did checked the latest docs, but it's still badly described.. e.g. not clear in which order it searches BBPATH and local dir, the following statement is odd:  "In order for include and class files to be found by BitBake, they need to be located in a "classes" subdirectory that can be found in BBPATH."  - do include files really must be located in classes subdir - that's not true, isn't it??

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. However, Stack Overflow is not the right place if you want improvements to happen - https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=BitBake%20User%20Manual would be a good place.